# Adicionar a uma categoria

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Não estou conseguindo fazer as novas tarefas adicionadas pertencerem a categoria selecionada no select.

```js
angular.module('TarefApp', []);

angular.module('TarefApp')

.controller('TarefasController', function($scope) {

  $scope.tarefas = [];

  $scope.addTarefa = function(tarefa) {
    for(var i=0; i < $scope.tarefas.length; i++){
        if($scope.tarefas[i].nome === tarefa.nome){
          alert("A tarefa já existe!");
          return;
        }
      }
    $scope.tarefas.push(angular.copy(tarefa));
    delete $scope.tarefa;
  };

  $scope.delTarefas = function() {
    var oldTarefas = $scope.tarefas;
    $scope.tarefas = [];
    angular.forEach(oldTarefas, function(tar) {
      if (!tar.selecionado) $scope.tarefas.push(tar);
    });
  };

  $scope.categorias = [];

  $scope.addCategoria = function(categoria) {
    for(var i=0; i < $scope.categorias.length; i++){
        if($scope.categorias[i].nome === categoria.nome){
          alert("A categoria já existe!");
          return;
        }
      }
    $scope.categorias.push(angular.copy(categoria));
    delete $scope.categoria;
  };
});
```

```css
.container {
    margin-top: 2%;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br" ng-app="TarefApp">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <!-- Bootstrap -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

   <!-- Angular.js minificado  -->
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 </head>
   <body>
     <div id="div-container" class="container" ng-controller="TarefasController" ng-controller="CategoriasController">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-3">
        <!-- Ínicio Adicionar Categoria -->
        <div class="page-header">
            <h4>Adicionar Categoria</h4>
          </div>
          <div id="div-form">
            <form role="form">
               <div class="form-group">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="categoria.nome">
               </div>
               <button class="btn btn-info btn-block" ng-click="addCategoria(categoria)" ng-model="infoIgual" ng-disabled="!categoria.nome">Adicionar</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <!-- Fim Adicionar Categoria -->
          <!-- Ínicio Adicionar Tarefa -->
          <div class="page-header">
            <h4>Adicionar Tarefa</h4>
          </div>
          <div id="div-form">
            <form role="form">
               <div class="form-group">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="tarefa.nome">
                 <br>
        <select class="form-control" id="category">
            <option ng-repeat="categoria in categorias">{{categoria.nome}}</option>
        </select>
               </div>
               <button class="btn btn-info btn-block" ng-click="addTarefa(tarefa)" ng-model="infoIgual" ng-disabled="!tarefa.nome">Adicionar</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <!-- Fim Adicionar Tarefa -->
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-9">
           <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="delTarefas()">Apagar tarefas selecionadas</button>

     <div ng-repeat="categoria in categorias">
            <h4 ng-model="categoria.selecionado">{{categoria.nome}}</h4>
            <div ng-repeat="tarefa in tarefas">
             <input type="checkbox" ng-model="tarefa.selecionado" ng-click="tarefaFeita()">
             <span class="done-{{tarefa.selecionado}}">{{tarefa.nome}}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
   </div>
     </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Efetuei alguns ajustes no teu código fonte. Primeiro problema você estava usando uma coleção de tarefas para todas as categorias. Por isso não conseguia distribuir corretamente as tarefas.

```html
<div id="div-container" class="container ng-scope" ng-controller="TarefasController">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <!-- Ínicio Adicionar Categoria -->
            <div class="page-header">
                <h4>Adicionar Categoria</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="div-form">
                <form role="form" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="categoria.nome">
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-block ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-click="addCategoria(categoria)" ng-model="infoIgual" ng-disabled="!categoria.nome" disabled="disabled">Adicionar</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- Fim Adicionar Categoria -->
            <!-- Ínicio Adicionar Tarefa -->
            <div class="page-header">
                <h4>Adicionar Tarefa</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="div-form">
                <form role="form" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="tarefa.nome">
                        <br>
                        <select class="form-control" id="category" ng-options="item.nome as item.nome for item in categorias" ng-model="categoriaSelecionada">

                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-block ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-click="addTarefa(tarefa)" ng-model="infoIgual" ng-disabled="!tarefa.nome" disabled="disabled">Adicionar</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- Fim Adicionar Tarefa -->
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="delTarefas()">Apagar tarefas selecionadas</button>
            <div ng-repeat="categoria in categorias">
                <h4 ng-model="categoria.selecionado">{{categoria.nome}}</h4>
                <div ng-repeat="tarefa in categoriaTarefa.tarefa[categoria.nome]">
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="tarefa.selecionado" ng-click="tarefaFeita()">
                    <span class="done-{{tarefa.selecionado}}">{{tarefa.nome}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```javascript
angular.module('TarefApp', []);
angular.module('TarefApp').controller('TarefasController', function($scope) {
    $scope.categorias = [];
    $scope.tarefas = [];
    $scope.categoriaTarefa = {tarefa:{}};

    $scope.addTarefa = function(tarefa) {
        if(!$scope.categoriaSelecionada){
            alert("Selecione uma categoria!!!")
            return;
        }
        var c = $scope.categoriaSelecionada;

        if(!$scope.categoriaTarefa.tarefa[c])
        $scope.categoriaTarefa.tarefa[c] = [];
        else{
            var itemDuplicado = false;
            angular.forEach($scope.categoriaTarefa.tarefa[c], function (item, index){
                itemDuplicado = (item.nome === tarefa.nome);
                if(itemDuplicado){
                    alert("Tarefa para categoria já existe!");
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }

        if(!itemDuplicado){
            $scope.categoriaTarefa.tarefa[c].push(tarefa);
            $scope.tarefa = {};
        }
    };

    $scope.delTarefas = function() {
        angular.forEach($scope.categorias, function(item) {
            var c = item.nome;
            var oldTarefas = $scope.categoriaTarefa.tarefa[c];
            $scope.categoriaTarefa.tarefa[c] = [];

            angular.forEach(oldTarefas, function(tar) {
                if (!tar.selecionado) $scope.categoriaTarefa.tarefa[c].push(tar);
            });
        });
    };

    $scope.addCategoria = function(categoria) {
        angular.forEach($scope.categorias, function(item) {
            if(categoria.nome === item.nome){
                alert("A categoria já existe!");
                return;
            }
        });

        $scope.categorias.push(categoria);
        $scope.categoria = {};
    };
});
```